# Swift Compiler Error: Segmentation-fault 11 thrown when using type constraints

Tags: swift, segmentation-fault, initialization, protocols, type-constraints

So, in swift I'm getting the following error:

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11, While emitting IR SIL function

when creating a new instance of a class by type-constraints in the following code:

```
public protocol AddOn {
    init()
    init(main: Main, name: String)
    func getId() -> String
    func description()
}


public class Foo : NSObject, AddOn {
    private var _main: Main?
    private var _name: String = ""
    required override public init() {

    }

    required public init(main: Main, name: String) {
        self._main = main
        self._name = name
    }

    public func getId() -> String {
        return "Foo"
    }

    public func description() {
        NSLog("Class: %@", self.getId())
    }
}

public class Main {
    private var _addons = Dictionary<String, AddOn.Type>()
    init() {

    }

    public func registerAddOn<T: AddOn>(addOnProtocol: T.Type) {
        // Here it is possible to Init the AddOn.Type to an object (e.q. Foo())
        let addOn: AddOn = addOnProtocol() as AddOn
        self._addons[addOn.getId()] = addOnProtocol
    }

    public func createInstance(addonClassName: String) {
        var getAddOnType: AddOn.Type = self._addons[addonClassName]!
        //Segmentation fault 11: While emitting IR SIL function
        let instance = getAddOnType(main: self, name: "Bar")
    }
}

var client: Main = Main()
client.registerAddOn(Foo.self)
client.createInstance("Foo")
```

At registerAddOn I am able to create a new instance of the class Foo, but not at createInstance

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the [Swift compiler crashes github](https://github.com/practicalswift/swift-compiler-crashes)

Comment: I solved the problem myself, I used AnyClass except of T.Type. Also thanks to Mgetz, the link gave me some new inspiration! My solution is added to the question.

Comment: I moved the solution to a Community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

```
private var _addons = Dictionary<String, AnyClass>()
    public func registerAddOn(addOnProtocol: AnyClass) {
        let addOnType = addOnProtocol as NSObject.Type
        let addOn: AddOn = addOnType() as AddOn
        self._addons[addOn.getId()] = addOnProtocol
    }

    public func createInstance(addonClassName: String) {
        var getAddOnType: AddOn.Type = self._addons[addonClassName]!
        let instance = getAddOnType(main: self, name: "Bar")
    }
}
```